# Failed login attempts log to database

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I ran into a problem, so when user attempts to login and it fails (wrong username & password entered) the data needs to be saved in database but it just won't work. 
If i put INSERT INTO in `if ($pw == $row['passwd']` it will work but I want to write it on else like in example.

```
    <?php
session_start();
require('connect.php');

$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $lastip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $lastip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $lastip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login_email`='$mail' AND `passwd`='$pw'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){$_SESSION['error'] = 1;Header("Location: login.php");}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($pw == $row['passwd'])
    {
    $_SESSION['logiran'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['mail'] = $mail;
    $_SESSION['error'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['sucess'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['subuser'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['subcid'] = $row['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `login` = '$time' WHERE `login_email`='$mail' AND `passwd`='$pw'";
    mysql_query($query);
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `last_ip` = '$lastip' WHERE `login_email`='$mail' AND `passwd`='$pw'";
    mysql_query($query);
    Header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `alerts`(`ipaddress`, `user`, `added`) VALUES ('$lastip', '$mail', '$time')";
    mysql_query($query);
    $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['logiran'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['subcid']  = 0;
    $_SESSION['subuser'] = 0;
    Header("Location: login.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `if($result){$_SESSION['error'] = 1;Header("Location: login.php");}` I Don't think it makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

@sense Yes, its wrong. it must be

```
if(!$result){some code}
```

But we want this:

If mysql_query INSERT INTO is on else it  doesnt work

```
    if ($pw == $row['passwd']){ some code }
else { here }
```

, but mysql_query INSERT INTO is on 
`if ($pw == $row['passwd']){ here }` then its works.

Comment: Please do not suggest edits to the original question that add the word "solved" to the title. Especially don't do this when it isn't your question. It is extremely presumptuous to assume your answer solves someone else's question. If the user who posted the question deems an answer to solve the problem, they will "accept" the answer and a green tick will show up next to that answer.

Comment: its my question, my mate posted it, and we solve it.

Comment: Nobody could have possibly known that given the different usernames. Regardless, if your mate agrees your answer solves the problem, then they can accept this answer by clicking the tick on the left hand side of the answer (when logged in as "Tuna"). This is how questions are marked as solved on Stack Overflow, not by editing the question title.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$result){$_SESSION['error'] = 1;Header("Location: login.php");}
```

remove this line than when wrong username or password will enter then it will save it in database.